# Ansible Error for windows cmd "start" for installing exe file

Tags: windows, ansible, command, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

Hello I am trying to install conda on remote windows server that do not have access to internet hence I am trying to copy the exe file to the server and then install. In windows I use 'start' command but with ansible I am getting the error as follow:

```
Could not find the file start.exe
```

My windows cmd is:

```
start /wait "" \\projects\tools\anaconda3.exe /InstallType= AllUsers /AddToPath=1 /S /D=D:\anaconda
```

my playbook:

```
- name : 'install anaconda'
win_command : 'start /wait "" \\projects\tools\anaconda3.exe /InstallType= AllUsers /AddToPath=1 /S /D=D:\anaconda'
args:
  chdir: 'D:\'
```

How to make ansibe recognize the 'start'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `win_shell` and specifying `cmd` as the executable :

```
- name : install anaconda
  win_shell : start /wait anaconda3.exe /InstallType=AllUsers /AddToPath=1 /S /D=D:\anaconda
  args:
    chdir: D:\projects\tools\
    executable: cmd
```